# Dynamically get GUID_SysMouse

Tags: c++, mouse, guid

How can i dynamically obtain GUID_SysMouse using C++? Without linking `dxguid.lib`. I need this because program, compiled with Windows 8 with linking `dxguid.lib` doesn't work with Windows XP Pro x86

Comment: This is an XY question.  Sure you can build a program on Win8 that targets XP, change your project's Platform Toolset setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing C++ enviroment, then dxguid.lib works ok!